# A headless CMS that includes visitor segmentation

Tags: cms

I'm looking for recommendations for a headless CMS where each individual blob of content can be targeted to a specific user segment.

Migrating from an in-house CMS where visitors are either guests or logged-in. And based on a bunch of parameters like auto-detected locale and browser type combined with logged-in profile parameters the user is put into a segment and each piece of content can have overrides for that segment... eg a generic 'Page Welcome' might read 'Hello' but there may also be a 'Page Welcome (US locale override)' reading 'Hey there'. The segments can be created by content editors based on segment attributes that are built by developers. The existing interface is a simple AND/OR builder for these attributes to be evaluated against.

Are there any headless CMS options that include any functionality that would contribute to a similar solution? I'm thinking that the creation of market segments piece would definitely need to be custom standalone, but I'm hoping something has the capacity to read in a list of segments and offer a content editing UI that allows editors to intuitively switch between these segments and edit the same blob of content for each segment or groups of segments.

Comment: "headless CMS" sounds for me like an iron icecube. Your title attracts attention (people first think: "w.f is this"), but it is not a good attention, imho. Although maybe persons with disabilities, like blind persons, could use a purely audio CMS, too, I never heard that it had been ever developed. I suggest to make clear already at beginning on your post, what do you understand on "headless" here.

Comment: Is headless-cms not a common term these days? For clarity I'm talking about a CMS that has a UI for editors but no UI for consumers. Content to be consumed purely by API.